# SQL : SELECT all rows with maximum values and with WHERE condition also

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I've table which look like this:

```
id  data    version rulecode
---------------------------
a1  1           100     x1
a2  1           100     x1
a1  1           200     x2
a4  2           500     x2
a7  2           200     x1
a6  2           500     x1
a7  2           500     x2
a8  2           150     x2
a9  3           120     x1
a10 3           130     x2
a10 3           120     x1
a12 3           130     x2
a13 3           130     x1
a14 3           110     x2
a15 3           110     x1
a16 4           220     x1
a17 4           230     x2
a18 4           240     x2
a19 4           240     x1
..........................
..........................
```

Now I want only those rows which has maximum `version` and  `data` value as *(1,2 and 4)*

When I tried with `dense_rank()`, I am getting only those rows which have `1` value from `data` column:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY version desc) as col
FROM public.table_name WHERE data in (1,2,4))x
WHERE x.col=1
```

Output:

```
id  data    version rulecode
---------------------------
a1  1           200     x2
```

**My expected output:**

```
id  data    version rulecode
a1  1           200     x2
a4  2           500     x2
a6  2           500     x1
a8  2           500     x2
a18 4           240     x2
a19 4           240     x1
```

Note: the value of `data` column is till millions.

Can someone help me out here to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY data ORDER BY version desc) as seqnum
      FROM public.table_name
      WHERE data in (1, 2, 4)
     ) x
WHERE x.seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(version) OVER (PARTITION BY data) max_version
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, data, version, rulecode
FROM cte
WHERE version = max_version AND data IN (1, 2, 4);
```

Note that we could have also filtered the `data` values inside the CTE.  I will leave it as is, for a general solution to your problem.